# ASP .NET MVC date time Format january 1st,2013 - 4:02 PM (EST)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to print date time like

```
July 18th,2013-04:05 PM(EST)
```

but it's showing for me like

```
January 1, 0001 - 00:00 (EST)
```

My code is given below.

For View

```
@System.String.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy} - {0:HH:mm} (EST)", Model.OrderDate)
```

For Model

```
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously `Model.OrderDate` is not initialized and has the default value January 1, 0001 (`DateTime.MinValue` or `default(DateTime)`). You need to assign `Model.OrderDate` the proper value in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use for standard date and time display.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dateToDisplay.ToShortDateString(), dateToDisplay.ToShortTimeString());
```